# How to convert the data in HTML to string in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make click the color code in the table, then when i click change button. the color of `<p>` will be change. 
here is HTML code.

```
 <button id="changijg" data-toggle="modal" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Change</button>
<p>changing color</p>
<table>
    <tr class='clickable-row'><td>334455</td></tr>
    <tr class='clickable-row'><td>FFFFFF</td></tr>
</table>
```

here is the JS code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function (event) {
    $(".clickable-row").not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $("#changingButton").prop("disabled", !$(this).hasClass('selected'));
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        var str ="color: #";
        //make the p color changing to the selected in the table
        $("p").prop("style", str);
});
```

I have try a lot of different method but none of them change the td to string. so what can I do to convert the data in td to string.

Comment: What is `changingButton` here?

Comment: you are missing some closing `}` in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used `$(this).text()` to retrieve the content and apply it with the Jquery `css()` function.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function (event) {
        $(".clickable-row").not(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    })

    $("#changeButton").click(function (event) {
       var selectedTD = $(".selected").first();
       var colorCode = "#" + selectedTD.text() 
       $("p").css("color", colorCode);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <button id="changeButton" data-toggle="modal" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Change</button>
<p>changing color</p>
<table>
    <tr class='clickable-row'><td>c90ee8</td></tr>
    <tr class='clickable-row'><td>334455</td></tr>
    <tr class='clickable-row'><td>FFFFFF</td></tr>
    <tr class='clickable-row'><td>2d89ff</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I updated my code so the color changed on the `Change` button as required in the spec.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).find("td").text()` to find the color value stored as HTML.

```js
$(".clickable-row").click(function(event) {
  $(".clickable-row").not(this).removeClass('selected');
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    var color = "#"+$(this).find("td").text();
    $("p").css("color", color);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="changijg" data-toggle="modal" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Change</button>
<p>changing color</p>
<table>
  <tr class='clickable-row'>
    <td>334455</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='clickable-row'>
    <td>FFFFFF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='clickable-row'>
    <td>FF0000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```